# I cannot make binding work with Diesel on MariaDB

Tags: mysql, rust, mariadb, rust-diesel

I simply wanted to pass an argument to my sql query.

```
let query = sql("SELECT resa_comment FROM reservation WHERE resa_id = ? ");

let query2 = query.bind::<Integer, _>(1286);

let result : Result<std::vec::Vec<String>, _> = query2.load(&connection);
dbg!(result);
```

But the result is

```
[src/bin/show_posts.rs:36] result = Err(
    DatabaseError(
        __Unknown,
        "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near \'?\' at line 1"
    )
)
```

The SQL query is correct because when I replace the "?" with a constant and remove the "bind", I get a correct result.

I know that I can map the table to a Rust structure but my goal is to pass complex requests with arguments so I was testing Rust and Diesel.

Is there something I missed ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bind` method does not replace question mark, it appends the value to the end of the query. So it should look like this:

```rust
let query = sql("SELECT resa_comment FROM reservation WHERE resa_id = ");
// ...
```

If you need to put value in the middle of the query, then you need to chain `bind` and `sql` calls, such as:

```rust
sql("SELECT resa_comment FROM reservation WHERE resa_id = ")
    .bind::<Integer, _>(1286)
    .sql(" AND something > ")
    .bind::<Integer, _>(1);
```

But note that you should avoid writing raw sql if it is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  About raw sql, it's a debate. For me, it's the best way to ensure the SQL query is perfectly optimized. Of course, we have to make sure that all parameters are correctly escaped to avoid SQL injection.